# Exact behavior of static keyword in java

Tags: java

Before, my code was:

```
class Dog
{
    public static int i=6;
}

public class Cat 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
    System.out.println(Dog.i);
    }
}
```

It executed well, but when I removed the class "Dog" from my code and recompiled it and run, it gave the same answer: 6.

So, my question is: Even though I do not have `Dog` class in my code, where does the variable `Dog.i` come from and why?

Comment: If you remove `Dog.` from that `System.out.println` line, the code no longer compiles.

Comment: I guess you forgot to save

Comment: Please only use *italics* and **boldface** for actual emphasis, rather than randomly applying them to entire paragraphs.

Comment: The connection with the `static` keyword escapes me. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't remove the Dog.class file. Otherwise compilation would have been impossible.

Comment: I suspect the OP just reran `javac`. Since the `Cat.class` was newer than `Cat.java` it might not be recompiled.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not much interested in speculation, but `javac` always recompiles files specifically named open the command line,

Answer (score 0):

One of the few optimisations the `javac` compiler does is constant inlining.  This means any primitive constant known at compile time can be inserted in place.  This means your code is the same as

```
public class Cat 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
    System.out.println(6 /*Dog.i*/);
    }
}
```

You can delete `Dog.*` and provided you don't recompile `Cat` it will run correctly.  Note: running `javac` again doesn't mean everything will be re-compiled, `javac` checks if the `.class` file is never than the `.java` file.

Also if you delete `Dog.java` this doesn't delete `Dog.class` and you only need the later to re-compile this class.

Comment: That doesn't fit the description *"when I removed the class "Dog" from my code"*. Failing to notice that it didn't compile a second time does (your comment on EJP's answer), and having the `extends Dog` does, but not that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't see how having `extends Dog` makes any difference as the constant has the class name included `Dog.i` When the the OP says he removed the class "Dog" it's not clear where this means just the `Dog.java` nor whether `Cat.class` was removed to ensure it was recompiled.

Comment: By "removed Dog" I figured he meant from the `System.out.println` line, given the context of the rest of the question and how it talks about wondering where `i` comes from. But fundamentally, this question isn't worth your time, mine, or EJP's until/unless it's clarified. :-)

Comment: This optimization only applies to `final` values. In this situation it does not occur.

Answer (score -2):

If you remove `Dog.` from that `System.out.println` line, the code no longer compiles. I'm going to assume you've left off `extends Dog` from your `Cat` class:

```
class Dog
{
    public static int i=6;
}

public class Cat extends Dog // <===== Note
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
    System.out.println(Dog.i);
    }
}
```

**If so**, the reason `i` resolves is that `Cat` *is a* `Dog`, and within code in the `Dog` class or its subclasses such as `Cat` (for `public` or `protected` members), static identifiers defined by `Dog` are in scope. You don't need to qualify them (though doing so can aid with clarity).

Comment: I'm not sure is this an answer, maybe supposition "what author mean"

Comment: @JacekCz: It's what fits the symptom the OP describes, so I'm fairly sure. I'll delete it if it turns out I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, your program is professionally correct (maybe un-natural iheritance), I doubt only at "didactic" level

Comment: @JacekCz: *"maybe un-natural inheritance"* I *also* put a comment about that in the above. :-D

Comment: If you removed Dog.class and Dog.java the code wouldn't compile whether Cat extended Dog or not.

Comment: @EJP: I don't read the question as them having done that. I read the question as them having done what I clearly said at the beginning of my answer.